# Apache configuration redirect from one url to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website *www.example.com* that is not going to work anymore and is actually being substitute with another website *www.new-name.com*.

Now, I want to ensure that users that go to www.new-name.com are redirected to the new domain.

I have several URLs in particular for which users might have bookmarked them. They correspond more or less to the same url but with the new domain. So not much changed between `abc` and `xyz` except the design and name.

What is the best way/approach to do it with an apache virtual host configuration file?

Is something like that a good practice:

```
   Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/en/some/link  https://www.new-name.com/some/link
```

I have not more than 5-6 such links, but I cannot actually use a RedirectMatch rule, since there is no pattern really.

Also, does this apache configuration reside on the server where the old website was hosted? (that is probably quite dummy questions, but I want to be sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match `http://` part in your pattern, so you have to use:

```
Redirect permanent /en/some/link  https://www.new-name.com/some/link
```

Or using regex support:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/en/(some/link/?)$  https://www.new-name.com/$1
```

This rule goes in the root .htaccess or Apache config of your old host.

Comment: Ok thanks! But is this a good practice to make such redirects? Is it efficient  ?

Comment: Of course it is. This is used very widely for situations like yours when moving site from one domain to another.